Gram-Schmidt process: kernel and image
Let $(V, \langle . , . \rangle)$ be a euclidian vector space and let $w \in V$ with $\Vert w \Vert = 1$. Let $f$ be a map with $f: V \to V, v \mapsto v - \langle v, w \rangle w$.
I'm supposed to find the image and the kernel of $f$. Is this correct:
im$(f) = \{v \in V \mid v \neq w \}$ and ker$(f) = \{w\}$?
For ker$(f)$, I thought $f(w) = w-1w = 0$ is obvious but what about the image? Is there a nicer way to describe the sets?

Some hints:

$f$ is a linear map, so the kernel and image should be subspaces. Currently, your answers are not subspaces.
What is $f(2w)$? What is $f(-w)$?
Drawing a picture when $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ or $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ can help with intuition.


Update in response to comment:
Your expressions for the kernel and image are correct, although the image could be more succinctly written as $\{z \in V : \langle z, w \rangle = 0\}$.
Here is an outline of how to turn the geometric intuition into a formal answer.

Intuition. Any vector $v$ can be decomposed into the sum of $\langle v, w \rangle w$ and $v - \langle v, w \rangle w$. The former is the component of $v$ that lies along the direction $w$, and the latter (which is your $f(v)$) is the component that lies in the space of vectors orthogonal to $w$.
Finding the image. Verify that $v - \langle v, w \rangle w$ is always orthogonal to $w$. This implies $\text{im}(f) \subseteq \{z \in V : \langle z, w \rangle = 0\}$. To show the $\supseteq$ direction, simply show that $\langle z, w \rangle = 0$ implies $z = f(z) \in \text{im}(f)$.
Finding the kernel. You want to find vectors $v$ satisfying $v - \langle v, w \rangle w = 0$, i.e. $v$ that have no component in the space of vectors orthogonal to $w$. That is, $v$ consists entirely of its component in the $w$ direction ($v = \langle v, w \rangle w$). From this we have $\ker(f) \subseteq \text{span}(\{w\})$. To show the $\supseteq$ direction, simply check that $f(cw)=0$ for any scalar $c$.


Ok, so I think that ker$(f) = { \alpha w \mid \alpha \in K }$ (with $K$ being the field that $V$ is defined over) which makes sense to me. And im$(f) = {z \in V \mid v - \langle v,w \rangle w = z$ for some $v \in V }$ so basically every vector $z$ that is orthogonal to $w$. Is that right? And is there a more formal way to prove it besides intuition? Thanks for the answer!

@metamathics Updated my answer
